# Disabling the "property's synthesized getter follows cocoa naming convention" warning

Tags: objective-c, properties, ios5

After upgrading Xcode to the 4.2, I'm going through and fixing all the new compiler warnings that I'm getting.  One that is in a lot of places is the "property's synthesized getter follows Cocoa naming convention for returning 'owned' objects" warning.  This is showing up in some code generated from web service WSDL files, so I don't want to change the property names just to satisfy a warning.  Is there a compiler flag to disable these warnings?  I've done the requisite googling, but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Can you change the getter names as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327448/semantic-issue-propertys-synthesized-getter-follows-cocoa-naming-convention-fo/6327547#6327547)?

Comment: I’ve added yet another solution to [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327448/semantic-issue-propertys-synthesized-getter-follows-cocoa-naming-convention-fo/6327547#6327547), namely specifying a different Objective-C method family.

Comment: Yes, if I change the getter or property name the warning goes away, but I was hoping there would be a compiler flag that I can set to ignore the warning - changing the third party code generator we're using to add getters where appropriate is doable, but a bigger deal than making a change in our codebase.  And I don't really want to change the generated code for all the obvious reasons (we regenerate fairly regularly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the consensus is that a compiler flag like this doesn't exist, so the best route (in my situation) is to try to get the third party code generator to handle this appropriately.