# Why can't I declare a variable like "newVariable" in Obj-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, variables

Error I got

```
error: property's synthesized getter follows Cocoa naming convention for returning 'owned' objects
/Users/.../ViewController.h:12:40: 

note: property declared here
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *newString;
```

why can't I use **new** in the variable name at the beginning? (like `newString`)

Comment: Because those naming conventions are enforced by the compiler.

Comment: so it got some other purpose in obj -c coding?

Comment: because new for convention is used for methods that return objects beeing retained by the caller

Comment: See here for a an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327448/semantic-issue-propertys-synthesized-getter-follows-cocoa-naming-convention-fo

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Declaring a property synthesizes two accessor (getter/setter) methods:

```
-(NSString*)newString;
-(void)setNewString:(NSString*)newString;
```

Objective-C has a naming convention for memory management that is enforced by the compiler.  Methods that start with `new` (also "alloc", "copy", "mutableCopy") are required to return an object that will be "owned" by the caller.  See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).  The generated accessor method doesn't follow the rule.

Answer (score 1):

This naming convention is already used in Objective-C. You will need to use something like just plain old `myString` to make this work. It's a compiler thing - compilers are *picky.*