# property's synthesized getter follows cocoa naming convention for returning 'owned' objects

Tags: objective-c, xcode, naming-conventions

Does Cocos2d have any naming conventions for variables?

I have this

```objectivec
//.h
NSMutableArray *newRowForCounter;
```

and

```objectivec
//.m
@synthesize newRowForCounter;
```

At `@synthesize` it's warning me that "property's synthesized getter follows cocoa naming convention for returning 'owned' objects". If I change the name to something else, it work fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365613/why-cant-i-declare-a-variable-like-newvariable-in-obj-c

Answer (score 48, accepted):

new cannot be used in the variable name at the beginning.
That is why it shows the error.

Sol : declare a property whose name begins with new unless you specify a different getter:

```
// Won't work:
@property NSString *newTitle;

// Works:
@property (getter=theNewTitle) NSString *newTitle;
```

Explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365613/why-cant-i-declare-a-variable-like-newvariable-in-obj-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327448/semantic-issue-propertys-synthesized-getter-follows-cocoa-naming-convention-fo)

Answer (score 0):

You can added an [NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#attr_ns_returns_not_retained) attribute to your property declaration to tell the compile that an 'owned' object is not returned here despite the "new" prefix in the property name, as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *newRowForCounter NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED;
```